# .exe from Python not working as expected

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I've created a simple program to search in a text file for a specific string.

I'm a beginner in coding, so I came up here, looking at different advises. One of these, was to use "Tkinter".

This is really great, but when I create an `.exe` with pyinstaller, the first part of the program run well (it opens the GUI where user have to choose the file), but then return an error, instead of asking which string to search (no problem running the `.py` file).

In my opinion, this is due to this part of the code:

```
option = raw_input('Enter string to find: ')
```

I 'think' it's because, generating an .exe, no gui infos are provided for this part of the code.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I've searched on Tkinter wiki, but I didn't found anything about this.

This is the code:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
option = raw_input('Enter string to find: ')

with open(filename) as searchfile: 
    found = False
    for line in searchfile:
        if option in line:  
            print line
            found = True

    if not found: print 'nothing found'
```

Comment: Isn't `raw_input` used for getting input from `stdin`, which is in most cases a terminal?

Comment: @leovp yes, that's the problem in my opinion too, but I don't know how to change it to make it work.

Comment: Who care your `input` if not call any `cmd` app ? Change your question title to **how to call gui and console from pyinstaller `exe` ?**

Comment: Could you provide us with the whole error message?